# Understanding Slowly Changing Dimension Type 2

Tags: data-warehouse, dimensional-modeling, star-schema, fact, scd

I am having difficult time understanding how to use slowly changing dimension type 2, in my scenario.
I have gone through different tutorial websites but they don't fit.

I have an employee dimension table containing:

```
+-----+---------------+------------+------------+
| id  | employee      | designation| Location   |
+-----+---------------+------------+------------+
| 1   | Ola           |   CEO      | Newyork    |
| 2   | Ahmed         | DEVELOPER  | California |
| 3   | Ola           | Manager    | California |
+----------+----------+------------+------------+
```

I have a Account Fact table

```
+-------+----------+
|emp_id | Amount   | 
+-------+-----------
| 1     | 2000000  |  
| 2     | 300000   | 
+----------+-------+
```

Now we see that the dimension has changed, and thus a new ID to same Ola employee has been given.
How would we manage in the fact table?

- The new ID of Ola will not be found in Fact Table.
- so if we add a new row in fact, with new ID of Ola, how would we link that they are same employee, when they are identified differently, 'primary key'.
- How would we distinguish this employee is not a new employee and actually location / designation has been changed.

Comment: I found this extremely helpful: http://datawarehouse4u.info/SCD-Slowly-Changing-Dimensions.html Especially the part where the data model for SCD 2 is being described. This also answers the distinguish part. In the fact table a date is missing to describe that in May Ola was in New York but in June he got to California. Maybe you have to add a snowflake table to describe unique employees.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am sure there are many ways of doing it, here's one way - Have an "employee_Key" in your dimension Table which is unique for an employee. So your dimension table will look like this -

```
 id  | emp_key | employee   | designation| Location   |Valid From| Valid To |
-----|---------|------------|------------|------------|----------|----------|
 1   | EMP1    | Ola        |   CEO      | Newyork    |1/1/1900  |1/1/2016  |
 2   | EMP2    | Ahmed      | DEVELOPER  | California |1/1/1900  |NULL      |
 3   | EMP1    | Ola        | Manager    | California |1/2/2016  |NULL      |
```

You can continue loading your fact table with the "New" ID for the employee. In this case you will have 2 different sets of Keys for that employee.

```
+-------+----------+
|emp_id | Amount   | 
| 1     | 2000000  |  
| 2     | 300000   | 
| 3     | 100000   |
+----------+-------+
```

If you want to rollup (say Sum of amounts) for an employee from the beginning, you would join the fact and dimension using the ID key and group by emp_key.
So,

```
select emp_key, sum(amount) from employee dim, account fact where dim.ID = fact.ID group by emp_key.
```

If you want to find out the amount since he became a manager, you just have to do rollup on the ID field.

```
select dim.ID, sum(amount) from employee dim, account fact where dim.ID = fact.ID group by dim.ID.
```

or this way -

```
select fact.ID, sum(amount) from account fact group by fact.ID.
```

Comment: Thanks. If I take a junk dimension for such changing attributes, wouldn't it be much better? What approach would you recommend?